# iterate over characters of string in chunks of 20 kotlin

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin, iteration, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying write a loop that will break down a template of strings and send it 20 bytes per iteration in kotlin.

```
fun verifySensor(template: String) {

    var previousValue = 0

    val iterationTimes = template.length / 20

    for (value in 1 until iterationTimes) {
        val templateByte = if (value == iterationTimes) {
            template.substring(previousValue until template.length - 1).toByteArray()
        } else {
            val subTemplate = template.substring(previousValue until (20 * value))
            subTemplate.toByteArray()
        }

        //Write the bytes to the sensor here
        writeToService(templateByte)
        previousValue += 20

        Log.i(TAG, "template >>> :: ${templateByte.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)}")


    }
    writeToService("VERIFY".toByteArray())


    Log.i(TAG, "Writing finger template in Byte")

}
```

I'm getting an output of >>

040c62008efa8675463a
f40785d3877b854870d8
b61b85d342f747ffd1f3
86648a877410fa2b887e
074b6ec8d16c887c9578
e6f8358586bac3f70bff
41a587c04af9d9ef394d
88132cebfe17d6c2881a
c19979fefae2889102ca
f3cf8ac48889c8f86b68
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
000000000000725a7353
95257462355224a396f2
0f000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000

But i'm expecting >>

040c62008efa8675463a
f40785d3877b854870d8
b61b85d342f747ffd1f3
86648a877410fa2b887e
074b6ec8d16c887c9578
e6f8358586bac3f70bff
41a587c04af9d9ef394d
88132cebfe17d6c2881a
c19979fefae2889102ca
f3cf8ac48889c8f86b68
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
000000000000725a7353
95257462355224a396f2
0f000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
000000000000733d

The last two lines of the expected output is being omitted

"00000000000000000000
000000000000733d"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, there are a couple off-by-one errors in your code.

You may find [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/chunked.html) extension function useful here:

```
fun verifySensor(template: String) {

    template.chunked(20).forEach { subTemplate ->
        writeToService(subTemplate.toByteArray())
    }

    writeToService("VERIFY".toByteArray())

}
```

Note that if your template string contains non-ascii characters, the encoded substring of 20 characters may be longer than 20 bytes. If that is a problem for your service, then you should convert string to bytes first, and send those bytes in chunks then.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, this division:

```
val iterationTimes = template.length / 20
```

is an integer division, so if the length of the string is not a multiple of 20 then the result will be the integer part of the division (for `length = 90` the result is `4`) and the calculated iterations will leave out the last part of the string (the remainder of the division `length / 20`). 
**Second**, when you use [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) to define a range, like this loop:

```
for (value in 1 until iterationTimes)
```

you should know that the upper limit is excluded.
So the iterations stop when `value` reaches `iterationTimes - 1` and you miss the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be wrong `val iterationTimes = template.length / 20`. For example;

`20 / 21 returns 1` but you should iterate 2 times. So maybe you can increase `iterationTimes` like `val iterationTimes = template.length / 20 + 1`

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me

```
fun verifySensor(template: String) {

    val raw = template.decodeHex().toByteArray()


    var index = 0
    while (index < raw.size) {
        val chunkSize: IntRange = if (index + 19 > raw.lastIndex) {
            IntRange(index, raw.lastIndex)
        } else {
            IntRange(index, index + 19)
        }

        val chunkList = raw.slice(chunkSize)

        val chunk = chunkList.toByteArray()
        Thread.sleep(350)
        index += 20

        writeToService(chunk)
    }
    Thread.sleep(350)
    writeToService("VERIFY".toByteArray())
}
```

Here ::

```
val raw = template.decodeHex().toByteArray()
```

I used Okio library https://github.com/square/okio to decode the strings of Hex

```
implementation "com.squareup.okio:okio:2.3.0"
```

I faced problems when trying to send the chunk of bytes, most of the bytes weren't sending to the service.
So, i had to sleep the thread for 350 milliseconds for each chunk of bytes to send completely.